# How can I find this product?

Tags: search

Is there a way to find someone that makes an item with a certain patent number?

Specifically, I'm looking for the product described in patent number 4,455,711.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the device described in any particular patent has ever been manufactured and sold. However, when there is a company listed as the assignee or applicant, then the most reasonable place to start is looking at the products produced by that company. In this case, the assignee is Hartwell Corporation. Its website is http://www.hartwellcorp.com. It looks like they make products for the aircraft industry and may not produce consumer products. Their website includes contact information so that is where you should follow up next.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's being offered in this catalog:
http://www.marek.eu/data/katalogy/776-cz-produkty_b-southco-b-uzaviraci-a-spojovaci-technika_panty_volne-otocne-panty_odnimatelne-panty_vnitrni-volne-odnimatelne-panty-f6-blokovatelne.pdf

Comment: Similar, but not the same device. Serves a similar purpose though. Southco is the manufacturer and their website is: https://www.southco.com/en-us/.

Comment: Well, they have part no. F6-35-1 labeled with the patent number in the OP, but I've not actually compared it to the patent.

Comment: That part is different than your link, and it is listed as "discontinued". F6-35-1 does look like what is in the patent however. Perhaps you could update your answer specifying the part number and then linking to Southco's website.

Comment: Also, I should have scrolled down and I would have seen the part you meant.